# JS Regex: starts with string, contains substrings in any order, ends with string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having users enter a JSON object into a text field and want to check to make sure it has a similar format to this:

```
{
    "address": "some string",
    "msg": "some string",
    "sig": "some string",
    "version": "some string"
}
```

I want it to start with `{` and end with `}` and check for `"address"`, `"msg"`, `"sig"`, and `"version"`.

So far I have this which works if it's in that *exact* format:

```
^{.*"address".+,.*"msg".+,.*"sig".+,.*"version".+}$
```

However, I would like the keys to be valid in any order. From my understanding, `(?=)` is used to search a forward looking string, I've tried the following and it doesn't seem to work....

```
^{.*(?="address".+,)(?="msg".+,)(?="sig".+,)(?="version".+).*}$
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: I’d personally `JSON.parse` the string and validate against the JS object instead of using regex to solve the problem. Just some thoughts.

Comment: May I ask why are you trying to solve this with regex? Wouldn't it be easier to first try to parse it as JSON with `JSON.parse()`, you will know if it's a valid JSON this way and catch the error if it isn't and then just check if your keys are inside of it?

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, but I've already seen those 2 posts and referenced them to come up with the above.

I hadn't thought about using JSON.parse, I'm going to see if that is feasible.

Comment: If you compared those two posts with what your wrote, you'd notice that they have `.*` before *each* sub-pattern to allow them to be matched in any position of the string, and yours doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blhsing pointed out, I was missing `.*` between each of the middle contain searched. This now works:

```
^{.*(?=.*"address".+,)(?=.*"msg".+,)(?=.*"sig".+,)(?=.*"version".+).*}$
```

However, as the comments suggested it would be better to solve this using `JSON.parse()`, which is what I ended up doing as it's a more robust solution:

```
const signedMsg = document.getElementById("signedMsg").value;
const correctFormat = signedMsg.includes(`{`) && 
                      signedMsg.includes(`"address"`) && 
                      signedMsg.includes(`"msg"`) && 
                      signedMsg.includes(`"sig"`) && 
                      signedMsg.includes(`"version"`) && 
                      signedMsg.includes(`}`);
let validJSON = false;
try {
  let test = JSON.parse(signedMsg);
  valid = true;
} catch {};

if (validJSON && correctFormat) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's not what I meant when I said having `.*` before each sub-pattern. What I meant is like `(?=.*"address")(?=.*"msg")`, which you can see from those two posts I linked to.

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, just updated it with your correction